# Image not displaying in jerkyll blog post

Tags: html, github, markdown

I tried to display an image in my github blog post(which I created using jekyll):

```
<img src = "./images/scatterplot.png" width="400" height="300" />
```

The image gets displayed in the markdown file but fails to output in the actual blog.
Any suggestions would be really helpful, thanks in advance !

As mentioned in one of the replies, I tried to open the image link : `https://surajsubramanian.github.io/posts/simple-linear-regression-from-scratch/images/scatterplot.png` 
This is strange, why does it take the name of my post in the path.

The path should have been  `https://surajsubramanian.github.io/posts/images/scatterplot.png`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here the correct link for the img:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SurajSubramanian/SurajSubramanian.github.io/master/_posts/images/scatterplot.png

To know the URL of a picture on the web browser (right click on the picture -> open the picture in new tab and you get thre right URL)

The img will be like that:

```
<img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SurajSubramanian/SurajSubramanian.github.io/master/_posts/images/scatterplot.png" width="400" height="300" />
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried to open the image link : ```https://surajsubramanian.github.io/posts/simple-linear-regression-from-scratch/images/scatterplot.png``` This is strange, why does it take the name of my post in the path. The path should have been  ```https://surajsubramanian.github.io/posts/images/scatterplot.png```

Comment: try to put the full path : <img src = "https://surajsubramanian.github.io/posts/images/scatterplot.png" width="400" height="300" />

Comment: Thanks man, https://github.com/SurajSubramanian/SurajSubramanian.github.io/blob/master/_posts/images/scatterplot.png this is the complete path, however the image is still not getting displayed in the path. Does this have anything to do with specifying an img tag in the middle of a markdown file

Comment: here the correct link for the img:https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SurajSubramanian/SurajSubramanian.github.io/master/_posts/images/scatterplot.png (right click on the picture -> open the picture in new tab and you get thre right URL)
The img will be like that:
<img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SurajSubramanian/SurajSubramanian.github.io/master/_posts/images/scatterplot.png" width="400" height="300" />

Comment: I've edited the first answer (PS: sorry for my english :) )